# How to make javax.faces.model.SelectItem selected

Tags: jsf

I'm creating a List of `javax.faces.model.SelectItem` (in a bean) for use with a `h:selectManyCheckbox` but I cannot figure out how to make a `SelectItem` selected.

How to do this? Must be possible, right?...

```
    public List<SelectItem> getPlayerList(String teamName) {
    List<SelectItem> list = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    TeamPage team = (TeamPage) pm.findByName(teamName);

    List<PlayerPage> players = pm.findAllPlayerPages();

    for (PlayerPage player : players) {
        boolean isMember = false;
        if (team.getPlayerPages().contains(player)) {
            isMember = true;
        }
        SelectItem item;
        if (isMember) {
            // TODO: Make SelectItem selected???
            item = null;
        } else {
            item = new SelectItem(player.getId(), createListItemLabel(player), "", false, false);
        }
        list.add(item);         
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume we have this JSF code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedValues}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.playerList}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

then the selected values (i.e. the checked checkboxes) are stored in the *bean.selectedValues* property.

Thus, in your Java code, you must handle the selectValues by putting the correct ID in the *selectedValues* property.

Answer (score -1):

If anybody is working with selectOneMenu and populating elements dynamically:
While creating a SelectItem, if you provide some value(first parameter) as follows:

```
new SelectItem("somevalue", "someLabel", "someDescription", false, false);
```

It translates to this in the html:

```
<option value="somevalue">someLabel</option>
```

If you do not provide a value as follows:

```
new SelectItem("", "someLabel", "someDescription", false, false);
```

, it translates to this

```
<option value="" selected="selected">someLabel</option>
```

Hence if you want an element to be the default on page load(like "Select one of these"), do not provide a value. If you create more than one element without a value, any one of them are chosen for default on page load(probably preference based on ascending alphabetical order).

Comment: I think your answer is not for this question. It's more an answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf and that already has a good (much better) answer than yours.