# disable or enable a inputTextarea in primefaces fail for second time

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I´m trying to `enable` or `disable` a `inputTextarea` by select a option in `selectOneMenu`.

If there is no value select it will be `disable` but if one value is select, will be `enabled`.

My problem is, I select a option and enable, i select no `option` and `disable`, and stop to refresh the component.

```
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lbl['LABEL.ALTERARPARA']}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{atendenteBean.statusAlterado}" label="#{lbl['LABEL.ALTERARPARA']}" converter="atendenteStatusConverter" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}"/>
                            <f:selectItems value="#{atendenteBean.statusPossiveis}" var="status" itemLabel="#{status.descricao}"/>
                            <p:ajax update="motivo" event="change"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>

                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:outputLabel value="#{lbl['LABEL.MOTIVO']}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <p:inputTextarea id="motivo" value="#{atendenteBean.pojo.motivo}" maxlength="100" cols="100" disabled="#{empty atendenteBean.statusAlterado}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
```

Comment: Use better the `noSelectionOption` attribute in your menu, in order of `#{null}` value. Take a [look](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11397505/1199132).

Comment: I used what you told but still having the same problem.

Comment: did you try `itemValue=""`?

Comment: I tested with PF 3.5 and JSF2.1.26 and it is working fine. Try to add some messages or isolate your problem an replicate in a new project. Review if your ajax call is been invoked after the second time (using developer tools)

Comment: I used to debug with setter and isn´t calling for the second time. What kind of tool you suggest?

Comment: from Chrome/IE Navigator (press F12)