# @NotNull not working on objects, but working on fields

Tags: jsf, bean-validation

I'm using @NotNull to define some atributes, but i want to use on relations as well.
So i did

```
@NotNull(message = "Região não pode ser nula")
@JoinColumn(name = "regiao_id", referencedColumnName = "regiao_id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Regiao regiaoId;
```

Just like i would do

```
@NotNull(message="O nome não pode ser nulo")
@Size(min = 1, max = 10)
@Column(name = "nome")
private String nome;
```

Using on a String it works fine, but it doesn't work on my relation objects, so i end up having to validate whit something like if`(foo.regiaoId() != null)` , can't i just make use of the @NotNull on situations like this as well?

To make it easy to understand i have an xhtml form where i dont want my selectOneMenu to be null

**my xhtml**

```
            <p:outputLabel value="Região:" for="regiaoCombo" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="regiaoCombo" value="#{equipamentoBean.equipamento.regiaoId}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione" itemValue="#{null}"></f:selectItem>
                <f:selectItems value="#{equipamentoBean.regioes}"></f:selectItems>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:message for="regiaoCombo"/>
```

Since i don't want to add to validate the nullable on my jsf, what would be the best way? Is there a way to use @NotNull on a object that belongs to a persistence class?

**REFs** using javax.validation.constraints.NotNull

[Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in conjunction with @NotNull

**@Basic(optional = false)** or **@Column(nullable = false)**

Here is a link to a clear and simple JPA documentation that might also help you http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/annotations

Comment: Doesn't really do what i want, i want to use as i use @NotNull as a validation bean, i tried both, but still the same results...