# hideNoSelectionOption in selectOneMenu is not working as expected

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have the following selectOneMenu and within of my component I want to have an item which shouldn't be shown, for e.g. in cases where the value from **#{Mybean.value}** match a value from **#{Mybean.ListValues}** I don't want to have an empty option in my combo box .

```
  <p:selectOneMenu value="#{Mybean.value}"  hideNoSelectionOption="true"     
   required="true" requiredMessage="Required data">

      <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{Mybean.ListValues}" var="option"  itemLabel="#{option.optionName}"   
      itemValue="#{option.optionId}"/>
 </p:selectOneMenu>
```

I searched, but I didn't find anything useful, just one link in [primefaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4713&sid=c08099b7d87503fc5bc631bf15566cc7) where describes exactly this problem.

My primefaces version is **3.5**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: it is supported from version 9 and on, see the other answer.**

That attribute [doesn't exist in the official api](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/) or in the [doc](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf). Where did you get it from?

---

What you're actually looking for is the [`itemDisabled` attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) on the `f:selectItems` component. It's this attribute that disables a selectItem from being selected. Historically, [primefaces has had problems with that attribute](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4127).

Ideally, you should have

```
   <p:selectOneMenu value="#{Mybean.value}" required="true" requiredMessage="Required data">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
       <f:selectItems itemDisabled="#{Mybean.value=='aValue'}" value="#{Mybean.ListValues}" var="option" itemLabel="#{option.optionName}"      itemValue="#{option.optionId}"/>
  </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @kolossus , in fact the attribute **hideNoSelectionOption** doesn't seem to be in primefaces 3.5, I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf/11397505#11397505 and also from the link I posted before.

Comment: The link you've referenced is referring to the **`<h:selectOneMenu/>`** not **`<p:selectOneMenu/>`** that you're trying to use @unpix; they're not the same and they're not interchangeable

Comment: You are right @kolossus, thanks. Since in my schema, h refers to JSF and p to PrimeFaces. So basically the answer to my question is here. I will mark as it is solved.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`hideNoSelectionOption` implemented in PrimeFaces 9.0

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/5886

PR: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/5909

Answer (score -2):

So, basically and based on @kolossus answer, we can in primefaces (when you are using  `<p:selectOneMenu`...) case add the following empty item

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--select--"  itemDisabled="#{Mybean.value ne null}" />
```

We can in primefaces (when we have to use

Note: In such case we don't need the following two tags:

```
hideNoSelectionOption="true"
```

and

```
noSelectionOption="true"
```

Comment: Why not just add this as a comment or small edit to the question?

Comment: I'm new on stackoverflow and I don't have enough reputation to comment on others posts.Thanks for the "-1" anyway...@Kukeltje

Comment: This post does not answer the question at all. Read the first paragraph of the question once more.

Comment: @BalusC : I tried the solution proposed by  Kukeltje but it didn't work.It worked is when I moved itemDisabled attribute to <f:selectItem instead of <f:selectItems.Also,mine does answer the posted question as it gives an alternative to using hideNoSelectionOption="true" when you are using primefaces.I could have just added a comment on the answer above but I don't have enough reputation to do so because I am new to stackoverflow.BTW, I think this reputation restriction should be removed as it pushes new developers to post instead of using comments until they have enough reputation...Thanks.