# Does hideNoSelectionOption attribute work for Primefaces?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have been following this link to achieve hiding of typical default 'select..' item of Primefaces dropdown after selecting another item:

[Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf)

This is not working for Primefaces.

Since the attribute `hideNoSelectionOption` is also not mentioned in Primefaces Showcase documentation, I doubt if this works for Primefaces.

Does anybody know an alternative for this in Primefaces?
I am using Primefaces version 5.3.

Comment: To be sure, you can easily check the sourcecode

Comment: I checked Primfaces source code. Looks like Primefaces does not support this feature right now. Maybe `h:selectOneMenu` supports this but to use that I'll have to apply Primefaces styling on top until I find a direct solution for Primefaces.

Comment: What is a direct solution? The source is open, a patch for a feature enhancement is easily made. If you create an issue in github for this, with a pull request might get it fixed even in the core

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258339/hidenoselectionoption-in-selectonemenu-is-not-working-as-expected