# disable/ enable primefaces components

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to disable some primefaces components after a selection from `p:selectOneMenu` but when I choose no selection option it still disabled

```
<p:outputLabel value="Manager" style="color:white;font-weight: bold;" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="manager" value="#{employeeMB.selectedManager}" immediate="true">
     <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selectionner..." noSelectionOption="true"/>
     <f:selectItems value="#{employeeMB.managers}"  />
     <p:ajax update="managerSelect role"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputLabel value="Est un Manager" 
               style="color:white;font-weight: bold;" />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="managerSelect" 
                         value="#{employeeMB.employee.isManager}" 
                         disabled="#{employeeMB.selectedManager != null}" />

<p:outputLabel for="role" value="Role Utilisateur" style="color:white;font-weight: bold;" />
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="role" value="#{employeeMB.selectedRoles}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Employée" itemValue="ROLE_EMPLOYEE" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Manager" itemValue="ROLE_MANAGER" itemDisabled="#{employeeMB.selectedManager != null}"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="RH" itemValue="ROLE_RH" itemDisabled="#{employeeMB.selectedManager != null}"/>
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That can happen when the updated model value is not `null`, but an empty string. You'd need to reconfigure JSF to interpret empty string submitted values as `null` to avoid the model being polluted with empty strings via below entry in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Nonetheless, better use `#{not empty bean.property}` instead of `#{bean.property != null}`. It also covers empty strings.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `noSelectionOption` is useless over there. Carefully read [Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf/) to understand it. I also have my doubts about your understanding of the `immediate` attribute there. Get rid of it. It has no sensible value anymore in JSF 2.x world thanks to all that ajax magic.