# <p:selectManyMenu var> throws ELException: The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'foo'

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectmanymenu

I am trying to implement primefaces `selectManyMenu` in advanced mode as shown in the showcase, however not able to get it work.

It works perfectly for `selectOneMenu` though.

Here is my code for selectOneMenu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="param" value="#{containerResultBean.selectedParam}"
                 converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" var="pa"
                 filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" >
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select questions" itemValue="" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{containerResultBean.paramList}"
                     var="parameter" itemLabel="#{parameter.name}"
                     itemValue="#{parameter}"/>
      <p:column >
           <h:outputText styleClass="mediumFont" value="#{pa.name}"/>
           <h:outputText styleClass="mediumFont" value="#{pa.category.name}"/>
      </p:column>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

for selectManyMenu

```
<p:selectManyMenu id="param" value="#{containerResultBean.selectedParamsList}"
                 converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" var="pa"
                 filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains" >
      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select questions" itemValue="" />
      <f:selectItems value="#{containerResultBean.paramList}"
                     var="parameter" itemLabel="#{parameter.name}"
                     itemValue="#{parameter}"/>
      <p:column >
           <h:outputText styleClass="mediumFont" value="#{pa.name}"/>
           <h:outputText styleClass="mediumFont" value="#{pa.category.name}"/>
      </p:column>
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

I am getting an error `value="#{pa.name}": The class 'java.lang.String' does not have the property 'name'.`

I have doubled checked, my `equal()`, `hashcode()` and `toString()` methods. I think if there is problem with these methods then `selectOneMenu` also should not have worked.

Please note, when i remove the `var='pa'` and `<column ...>`, it works perfectly.

Comment: Is `containerResultBean.selectedParamsList` a *list* object? It seems `pa` is taken like a String object.

Comment: @Miguel yes, selectedParamsList is a list object. `private List<Param> selectedParamsList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Miguel i dont understand why it is taken as a String object in ManyMenu and not in OneMenu?

Comment: I'm not familiarized with Omnifaces but perhaps the problem is the converter. Sorry, I don't know Omnifaces and I can help you more. I'll be close for helping you with other possible issue.

Comment: @Miguel thanks, but Omnifaces converter is using toString method of the class and is similar to what one implements by his own. Converter is simply  converting the Entity object to String and from String, back to Entity. Therefore if there is a problem with converter than OneMenu should not work too. This is what my understanding about converters is..

Comment: Moreover, the converter only applies to `<f:selectItem(s)>`, not to the customized representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by the placeholder item which has an empty string as value.

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select questions" itemValue="" />
```

Better explicitly make it `#{null}` instead of an empty string so it resolves to `null` instead of `java.lang.String`.

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select questions" itemValue="#{null}" />
```

It worked in `<p:selectOneMenu>`, because its renderer simply renders the label when the item value is an [instance of `String`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/7a640b825cee43e0f874441df156525bd0321a32/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/selectonemenu/SelectOneMenuRenderer.java#L260) (which would in turn thus fail if it's actually `null`; this is in turn likely an oversight/bug in PrimeFaces).

#### See also:

- [Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf/)

Comment: thanks it worked, but why does the empty string in <f:selectItem..> causes problem in ManyMenu and not in OneMenu?

Comment: I just looked into its source code and updated the answer.

Comment: Got it why it was working in OneMenu..but what do you mean by it would fail if its `null`? what is null?

Comment: `<p:selectOneMenu>` will show an empty custom item if you used `itemValue="#{null}"` in there.