# p:selectOneMenu doesn't render custom content via p:column on List<String>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I'm trying to get a Primefaces 5.2 selectOneMenu to display images along with their filenames. This is what my xhtml currently looks like:

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid id="createPanelGrid" columns="2">
    <p:outputLabel value="Service Logo:" />
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{imageBean.selectedImage}" var="l">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a logo" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{imageBean.imageList}" var="logo" itemLabel="#{logo}" itemValue="#{logo}" />
        <p:column>
            <p:graphicImage value="#{imageBean.imageFolder}/#{l}" style="max-width:50px;max-height:50px;" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>#{l}</p:column>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGrid>
```

The ManagedBean (imageBean) has

```
public List<String> getImageList () {
    List<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] files = absoluteImageFolder.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        imageList.add(file.getName());
    }        
    return imageList;
}
```

and

```
private String selectedImage;

public String getSelectedImage() {
    return selectedImage;
}

public void setSelectedImage(String selectedImage) {
    this.selectedImage = selectedImage;
}
```

However, the images are not rendered on the webpage, just the filenames (I'd post a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation). I don't get two columns (first the image, then the filename), I just get the filename itself.

When I wrap the filename Strings into a POJO and use a converter it works - but just with Strings it doesn't.

How can I get this to work with just Strings?

Comment: No 404s in the log - also the same URLs do work when I use a wrapper class around the filename Strings. If I'd found a clue in the logs that I could interpret I wouldn't have posted.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to say that there are no clues in the logs, just that I can't spot any. Can you give me a hint what I'm looking for (other than 404s, for which I checked)? Also, what confounds me is that changing things on the server side (adding the wrapper class) makes it work.

Comment: No, the desired <img> element doesn't end up in the HTML output - it's omitted. Instead, I get just the text (filename). If I use the wrapper class, I get the <img> tag without problems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This awkward behavior is confirmed by [`SelectOneMenuRenderer` source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_2/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/selectonemenu/SelectOneMenuRenderer.java#L260) (line numbers match 5.2):

```
260            if(itemValue instanceof String) {
261                writer.startElement("td", null);
262                writer.writeAttribute("colspan", columns.size(), null);
263                writer.writeText(selectItem.getLabel(), null);
264                writer.endElement("td");
265            } 
266            else {
267                for(Column column : columns) {
268                    writer.startElement("td", null);
269                    renderChildren(context, column);
270                    writer.endElement("td");
271                }
272            }
```

So, if the item value is an instance of `String`, custom content via `<p:column>` is totally ignored. This does indeed not make any sense. The intuitive expectation is that the custom content is toggled by presence of `var` attribute and/or `<p:column>` children. You'd best report an issue to PrimeFaces guys to explain/improve this.

The work around, apart from providing non-`String`-typed item values, is to override the `SelectOneMenuRenderer` with a custom renderer which wraps the `String` in another object which happens to return exactly the same value in its `toString()`, such as `StringBuilder`. This way the renderer will be fooled that the values aren't an instance of `String`. Glad they didn't check for `instanceof CharSequence`.

```
public class YourSelectOneMenuRenderer extends SelectOneMenuRenderer {

    @Override
    protected void encodeOptionsAsTable(FacesContext context, SelectOneMenu menu, List<SelectItem> selectItems) throws IOException {
        List<SelectItem> wrappedSelectItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SelectItem selectItem : selectItems) {
            Object value = selectItem.getValue();

            if (value instanceof String) {
                value = new StringBuilder((String) value);
            }

            wrappedSelectItems.add(new SelectItem(value, selectItem.getLabel()));
        }

        super.encodeOptionsAsTable(context, menu, wrappedSelectItems);
    }

}
```

In order to get it to run, register it as below in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.SelectOneMenuRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.YourSelectOneMenuRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Comment: Wow... Thanks a ton! I would never have thought that this behaviour is intentional...
And double thanks for providing the nice workaround!

There's a small glitch with the workaround when you use (non-String) POJOs if you have a "non item" like the
`<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select a logo" itemValue="" />`
in my example - you get a PropertyNotFoundException because the POJO's properties can't be found on the StringBuilder object.
My (lazy) fix is to use in the renderer
`if (value instanceof String && !"".equals((String) value)) {`

Comment: You're welcome. As to the glitch, you should have used `itemValue="#{null}"`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf

Comment: Ah, thanks - I'll use that.
BTW: I've posted in the Primefaces forum and asked about this issue, let's see what they say.

Comment: The more I look at it, the more I suspect that this special behaviour for Strings in Primefaces is meant just for the case of adding a non-option.
Sadly, if you use #{null} as the itemValue, the condition in line 260 is false, so you go to the else-branch. This then renders a missing image with an empty filename. I assume I do have to add special treatment for null and/or empty strings.
From your answer here [http://stackoverflow.com/a/11397505/1685666] I assume that this is not standard JSF behaviour. Oh well.

Comment: but it is associated with string not with object, so if i want to pass object to bean how i can do that?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that Primefaces library is especting a bean in the `var` attribute of the `selectOneMenu` component, but you are giving String objects which are not beans . So the library doesn't render any column overlay at all. You will need a bean (wrapper) in the `var` attribute and the corresponding Converter in the `converter` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, that's the workaround that works for me - I had just hoped that there was a simpler way...

Comment: That is the question, there is no workaround because there is nothing to workaround. That is the way for putting images in a Primefaces selectOneMenu. If my answer clarify your question please accept my answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Thank you.

Comment: So a String is not a POJO?

Comment: I meant bean, instead of pojo.

Comment: but it is associated with string not with object, so if i want to pass object to bean how i can do that?

Comment: create a bean class with a property returning the String value. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-populate-options-of-hselectonemenu-from-database