# PrimeFaces SelectOneMenu with icons (custom f:selectItems)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to display all available FontAwesome icons in a `p:selectOneMenu` component.

The renderer is supposed to render the icon first, then display the icon's name. A **similar** example can be found here but is implemented especially for BootStrap: https://mjolnic.com/fontawesome-iconpicker/

```
 ----------------------------------
|- ICON - | Icon name              |
 ----------------------------------
```

Unfortunately, the custom columns just do not get rendered. The `p:selectOneMenu`appears but is rendered as by default.

My picker xhtml page looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"> 

<h:head></h:head> 
<body>
    <p:panel>
        <h:form id="iconPicker">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="iconSelectOneMenu"
            value="#{iconController.availableIconStrings}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose icon"
                noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems
                value="#{categoryController.availableIconStrings}"
                var="_icon" itemValue="#{_icon}"
                itemLabel="#{_icon}" />
                <p:column>
                    <p:button id="iconButton" icon="#{_icon}" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{_icon}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>
</body> 
</html>
```

The `IconController` class:

```
public class IconController implements Serializable {

    private List<String> availableIconStrings;

    public IconController() { }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        availableIconStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        availableIconStrings.addAll(Arrays
                .asList("fa-adjust,fa-adn,fa-align-center,fa-align-justify,fa-align-left,"
                        + "fa-align-right,fa-ambulance,fa-anchor,fa-android,fa-angellist,"
                        + "fa-angle-double-down,fa-angle-double-left,fa-angle-double-right,"
                        + "fa-angle-double-up,fa-angle-down,fa-angle-left,fa-angle-right"
                        // Shortened list
                        .split(",")));
    }

    public List<String> getAvailableIconStrings() {
        return availableIconStrings;
    }

    public void setAvailableIconStrings(List<String> availableIconStrings) {
        this.availableIconStrings = availableIconStrings;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to render the icon using a `p:button`. Do I understand it correctly that I need a PrimeFaces component that is able to display icons (e.g. `p:button`, `p:commandButton`, `p:commandLink`) to achieve my goal?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

P.S.: Using PrimeFaces 5.3, JSF 2.2 and Mojarra on WildFly 9.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

In order to use `p:column` in combination with `p:selectOneMenu` you need to declare the `var` attribute on the `p:selectOneMenu` and reference it within your `p:column`. An example can be found on the [PrimeFaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml).

So your code should be:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="iconSelectOneMenu"
        value="#{iconController.availableIconStrings}" var="ic">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose icon"
            noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems
            value="#{categoryController.availableIconStrings}"
            var="_icon" itemValue="#{_icon}"
            itemLabel="#{_icon}" />

            <p:column>
                <p:button id="iconButton" icon="#{ic}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{ic}" />
            </p:column>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Now, You are facing a bug because you are using a `List<String>` as explained on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32735770/pselectonemenu-doesnt-render-custom-content-via-pcolumn-on-liststring) SO question:

> So, if the item value is an instance of String, custom content via `p:column` is totally ignored.

You can find a workaround in the same post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32740430/2118909

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity and re-usability, I decided to wrap the `String`s in an `Icon` class and not to follow implement a different `Renderer` class as suggested by BalusC in the workaround (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32740430/2118909).

```
    public class Icon {

    private String fontIconName;

    public Icon(String fontIconName) {
        this.fontIconName = fontIconName;
    }

    public String getFontIconName() {
        return fontIconName;
    }

    public void setFontIconName(String fontIconName) {
        this.fontIconName = fontIconName;
    }
}
```

The JSF page looks as follows:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="iconSelectOneMenu"
    value="#{iconController.selectedIcon}" var="_icon" converter="#{iconConverter}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose icon"
        noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems
        value="#{categoryController.availableIcons}" itemValue="#{_icon}"
        itemLabel="#{_icon.fontIconName}" />

        <p:column>
            <i class="fa fa-fw #{_icon.fontIconName}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{_icon.fontIconName}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Please also note the following:

- `#{iconController.selectedIcon}` now refers to an instance of the `Icon` class
- `#{iconController.availableIcons}` now refers to a `List<Icon>` instance
- I have added a `Converter` for the `Icon` class.
- The icon is now rendered in an `<i/>` element.

Please also note the importance and role of the `customContent` variable in the [`SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodePanel(...)`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/5_3/src/main/java/org/primefaces/component/selectonemenu/SelectOneMenuRenderer.java#L208) method which indicates that you need a `var` value on the `p:selectOneMenu` directly (not in the `<f:selectItems/>` element!) or the renderer will not recognize that there is custom content as it does not evaluate the `<f:selectItems/> var` attribute.

Comment: Why not create an issue in the PF issuelist  in github with a patch (pullrequest) so this 'workaround' will not be needed in the future

Comment: @Kukeltje Please see: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1036 (created an issue at least) and hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use inputGroup

```
   <div class="ui-inputgroup">
       <div class="ui-inputgroup-addon"><i class="pi pi-user"></i></div>
       <p:inputText placeholder="Username"/>
   </div>
```

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputGroup.xhtml

Comment: The question is about `p:selectOneMenu`

Comment: Just I add for example, ui-inputgroup compatible with all primeface components, its writed by primeface

Comment: There actually is an example for `p:selectOneMenu` in the showcase based on a workaround I've provided. See my answer for the workaround and a link to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml for an example:

```html
<p:outputLabel value="Icons" />
<h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-inputgroup">
    <h:panelGroup id="icon" styleClass="ui-inputgroup-addon">
        <i class="pi pi-#{selectOneMenuView.icon}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{selectOneMenuView.icon}" var="item">
        <f:selectItems value="#{['flag','wallet','map','link']}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item}"
            itemValue="#{item}" />
        <p:column><i class="pi pi-#{item}" /> #{item} </p:column>

        <p:ajax update="@parent:@parent:icon" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

[image: Screenshot]

It is a workaround, yes, but it's the best option currently.

See also:

- https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6140