# How to submit null value of p:selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have file `submission.xhtml` with code snippet:

```
<p:outputLabel for="cbFilterPlanYear" value="Choose time period"/>

<p:outputPanel>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="cbFilterPlanMonth" value="#{SubmissionController.miFilterMonth}" style="width: 50%">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{null}" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{SubmissionController.mlistMonth}" var="month" itemValue="#{month}" itemLabel="#{month}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" update="@this" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:selectOneMenu id="cbFilterPlanYear" value="#{SubmissionController.miFilterYear}" style="width: 50%">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{null}" itemValue="#{null}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{SubmissionController.mlistYear}" var="year" itemValue="#{year}" itemLabel="#{year}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" update="@this" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:outputPanel>
```

These line of code for search criteria(s), for filter data. **I can't submit NULL value** (As you know, it also don't set specific criteria to search query). Help me submit null value from `p:selectOneMenu`.

[image]

Comment: why you can't submit null value?
if you no select any value in the select, your field in managedbean will be null

Comment: It can't send `null` value. It keep old value, for example, if I choose May month before, it keep value `5`, don't change to `null`, when I submit.

Comment: really, see the @inafalcao's answer. i think `noSelectionOption="true"` fix your problem

Comment: Please do not use [java] tag when asking JSF questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could put just an empty string on your f:selectItem instead of `itemLabel="#{null}" itemValue="#{null}"` and add the attribute `noSelectionOption="true"`

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

Example [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml) on primefaces docs.

Comment: has no problem in use `itemLabel="#{null}"` and  `itemValue="#{null}"`
But, I think that `noSelectionOption="true"` fix the problem

Comment: I have no way to test this, but at least the empty string is less verbose, I think. :)

Comment: When I choose null value, It doesn't work, even it doesn't call method at controller when I press submit button.

Comment: If the value of the selectOneMenu is a string there's no difference.
However, it can be a object of another class

Comment: In either case, edited my answer to put this as an enhancement.

Comment: @dovy, paste the snippet of your submit button

Comment: Instead of posting a "try this" / "I think" answer, please first try to reproduce the described problem yourself and test the potential solution yourself. If you're unable to, post a comment instead of an answer. At least, the `noSelectionOption` serves an entirely different purpose than what you're saying here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf

Answer (score -1):

you can do like that :`<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="" />`

Comment: When I choose `null` month or `null` year, even it doesn't call method `search(...)` at controller.

Comment: `public final void search() {
 try {
  mlistSubmission = msubmissionModel.search(strSearchSubmitNo, miFilterYear, strSearchSubmitType, mfilterOrg.getOrgCode(), miFilterMonth);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  SystemLogger.getLogger().error(ex);
  ClientMessage.logErr(ClientMessage.MESSAGE_TYPE.ERR, ex.toString());
 }
}`