# Blank h:selectOneMenu without blank item in dropdown list

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to display blank value onload of h:selectonemenu without adding blank item in dropdown list. But i am not able to get it.

I tried with a few scenario by adding `display:none` but to no avail.
I even tried adding css but it too didnt work.

Please find the below code:

```
  <h:selectOneMenu
   id="testid" style="width:22%;" maxlength="29"
   value="#{myVal.val}" >
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" style="display:none;"/>
   <f:selectItems
   value="#{myController.animalsData}" var="data" itemLabel="#{data.animalName}"
itemValue="#{data.animalCode}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: How would you do this in plain html?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf