# Select default value on h:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, javabeans, selectonemenu

I am new on JSF and i am having some problem with h:selectOneMenu
I have combo1 with countrys and combo2 with citys, I want to reload combo2 when combo1 changes and always leave combo2 with a default value (--select--).
I am using ajax event to reload values and that works fine, but I can't leave the default value I want every time it changes.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{bean.country}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="--Select--" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getCountrys()}" />
  <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.getCitys}" render="city" execute="@this"></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{bean.city}">
  <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="--Select--" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getCitys()}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Edit:
Thanks for the responses, but it didnt solve the problem.  Let me give you a full a example to make it more clear (my english is bad...) .  The problem is when the second selection has the same value than the first one, example.
Combo 1 flags:
1.Germany
2.Italy
3.Spain
4.France

Combo2 colors.
(selected germany)
1. Black
2. Red.
3. Yellow

I select black!, then I select in combo 1 Italy, as italy flag doesnt have the black color on it it gets back to --Select--  But, if Italy flag would have the black color it reloads the rest of the values but leaves black as selected, instead of get back to --select--
Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just add the `itemValue="#{null}"` and `noSelectionOption="true"` attributes to the `<f:selectItem>` tag.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{bean.city}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Select--" noSelectionOption="true"/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.getCitys()}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Originally anwered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didnt solve the problem.  Let me give you a full a example to make it more clear (my english is bad...) .  The problem is when the second selection has the same value than the first one, example.

Comment: @SebastianMotavita: If you find a duplicate, you can flag the question as such instead of creating an almost identical answer and splitting 'discussion'. For most 'basic' problems, there already is an answer as you found out..

Comment: @user3285427: Well, I thinl that when you are updating the second combo (which has the city value of the bean, maybe a String), it is getting the value of bean.city, which is saved from previous selection, in this case 'Black', maybe the method getCitys is not updating as you which.