# p:selectOneMenu and parameterizable noSelectionOption (required = true), hideNoSelectionOption missing

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I just came across [Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf) and I was wondering how to (best) implement a `p:selectOneMenu` that gets included via `ui:include` and gets an option to say whether the component is to display a null (Please select...) entry or not:

```
        <p:selectOneMenu id="#{id}"
                         value="#{value}"
                         converter="#{not empty converter ? converter : idEntityConverter}"
                         required="#{not empty required ? required : false}"
                         requiredMessage="#{not empty requiredMessage ? requiredMessage : commontext['message.required']}"
                         hideNoSelectionOption                         ????
                         rendered="#{commonf:isAllowed(not empty allowed ? allowed : true, benutzerRecht)}"
                         disabled="#{not empty disabled ? disabled : false}">

            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{commontext['common.action.pleaseSelect.label']}" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectableEntities}"
                           var="ent"
                           itemValue="#{ent}"
                           itemLabel="#{not empty labelExpression ? labelExpression : ent}"
                           itemDisabled="#{not empty disabledExpression ? disabledExpression : false}" />

        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

As the aforementioned SO posting shows, the standard JSF `h:selectOneMenu` way is to use the `hideNoSelectionOption` attribute, which is missing in the `p:selectOneMenu`.

**Q**:

Since `f:selectItem` is a tag handler the question is: how do you tell the above component that if the field is required, that the `p:selectOneMenu` shall not render the noSelectionOption `f:selectItem` (disabling it is not desired)?

The question has already been raised a long time ago without an answer in the PrimeFaces forum here: https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=8028

Comment: f:selectItem tag has the "itemDisabled" attribute. Maybe if you set in your null valued item the following: itemDisabled="#{not empty required ? required : false}"

Comment: why not adding an ajax event ?!? (on change)