# PrimeFaces: Passing selected value to Autocompele-Method (Request-Scope)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a requirement that is currently not straightforward to implement. The autocomplete function should be preselected here based on a `SelectOneMenu` selection. For this, I need the previously selected value in the `completeMethod`.
In general, the list returned from the completeMethod should be filtered by the selected value.

I have tried to solve the problem using `f:attribute`. Unfortunately, the value is always null here because I am using a request-scoped bean.

Here is the code for my current attempt:

**View:**

```
      <h:form id="myForm">
            <h:outputLabel value="My Selection" for="selectFldId" />
            <p:selectOneMenu
                value="#{autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean.selectedValue}"
                id="selectFldId">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""
                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems
                    value="#{autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean.selectItems}" />
                <p:ajax event="change" update="autoCompleteId" process="@this" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>


            <p:autoComplete
                disabled="#{empty autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean.selectedValue}"
                value="#{autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean.completedText}"
                id="autoCompleteId"
                completeMethod="#{autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean.completeText}">
                <f:attribute name="filter"
                    value="#{autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean.selectedValue}" />
            </p:autoComplete>
    </h:form>
```

**Bean:**

```
@Named(value = "autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean")
@RequestScoped
public class AutocompleteWithPreSelectionBean implements Serializable {
    private List<SelectItem> selectItems;
    private String selectedValue;
    private String completedText;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        selectItems = new ArrayList<>();
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("ID1", "Value 1"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("ID2", "Value 2"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("ID3", "Value 3"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("ID4", "Value 4"));
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem("ID5", "Value 5"));
    }

    public List<String> completeText(String query) {

        String filterValue = (String) UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getAttributes()
                .get("filter");
        
        //selectedValue is null
        //filterValue is null
       ... 
       }
...
}
```

Is there a solution for my requirement where I can continue to use a request-scoped bean? Other approaches or solutions are also welcome.

I'm using Faces 4 with PrimeFaces 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two factors contributing to the observable problem.

The `disabled` attribute is also evaluated during Apply Request Values phase, at the moment Faces needs to collect the submitted value and queue the autocomplete event. You've specified it as follows:

```xml
<p:autoComplete ... disabled="#{empty autocompleteWithPreSelectionBean.selectedValue}">
```

But this will **always** evaluate `true` in case of a request scoped bean because the `selectedValue` is already cleared out and is only set during Update Model Values phase. That's *after* the Apply Request Values phase. So there's no way that this will ever evaluate `false` and therefore the autocomplete component is basically permanently disabled during apply request values phase.

One way to fix this is to let it check the request parameter associated with the dropdown component instead of the model value associated with the dropdown component.

```xml
<p:selectOneMenu ... binding="#{selectFld}" />
<p:autoComplete ... disabled="#{empty param[selectFld.clientId += '_input']}" />
```

In case you're using PrimeFaces [Partial Submit](http://www.primefaces.org:8080/showcase/ui/ajax/partialSubmit.xhtml) feature, then this will only work when you add the following `<p:ajax>` to the autocomplete component which explicitly instructs ajax to also send the submitted value of the dropdown component along:

```xml
<p:autoComplete ...>
    <p:ajax event="query" process="@this selectFldId" update="@this" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

Secondly, in order to get the bean property associated with the dropdown component to be already prepopulated in the autocomplete method, I expected the afore demonstrated `<p:ajax>` to be sufficient in achieving the task:

```java
public List<String> completeText(String query) {
    System.out.println(selectedValue); // Should already be populated.
    // ...
}
```

However, I was surprised to observe that this was still `null`. Then I debugged a bit and was yet more surprised to observe that the complete method was invoked during Apply Request Values phase instead of the expected Invoke Application phase! I'm not sure if that was intentional.

So best we could do is indeed to continue the `<f:attribute>` trick but then this time reusing the request parameter map trick as used in `disabled` attribute:

```xml
<p:autoComplete ...>
    <f:attribute name="filter" value="#{param[selectFld.clientId += '_input']}" />
</p:autoComplete>
```

```java
public List<String> completeText(String query) {
    String filterValue = (String) UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getAttributes().get("filter");
    // ...
}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `noSelectionOption="true"` is not properly understood here. It's basically completely ignored in your context. Use `itemValue="#{null}"` instead. See also [Best way to add a "nothing selected" option to a selectOneMenu in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360030/best-way-to-add-a-nothing-selected-option-to-a-selectonemenu-in-jsf).

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. The approach seems to be working.
I also didn't expect that the autocomplete function is executed in the "Apply Request Values" phase. With this knowledge, the behavior at least makes some sense.